# Копирование определённых строк из одного файла в другой

Tags: python, python-3.x, copy

Суть такова:
Имеется файл с таким содержимым: [ссылка на файл](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/SonyCustoms/device_sony_tuba/oreo/sepolicy/file_contexts)

Нужно скопировать ТОЛЬКО строки заканчивающиеся на `_exec` в другой файл.

В сети видел что-то подобное с помощью `shutil`, только не смог понять как это применить в моём случае. Или есть более простые методы?

Спасибо!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
with open('input.txt') as source, open('output.txt', 'w') as destination:
    for line in source:
        if line.strip().endswith('_exec'):
            destination.write(line)
```

Comment: подскажите, пожалуйста, как вывод можно в список преобразовать в данном случае?

Comment: Не понял вас, поясните.

Comment: https://gist.github.com/andrwgldmn/0411eb41deddb11b252a2cc640e70182

Comment: Исправил, проверьте.

Comment: чтобы всё работало нужно исправить ещё с _exec на _exec:s0. Теперь всё в порядке!

Answer (score 1):

Вот с использованием регулярного выражения - записать в другой файл:

```
import re
with open('file.txt') as source, open('output.txt', 'a') as destination:
    www = source.read()
    for string in www.split('\n'):
        wert = "".join(re.findall('(^.*_exec.*$)',string))
        if wert:
            destination.write(wert+'\n')
```

Comment: Нужно записать в другой файл, а не просто найти. 2. Что будет, если в файл записать список, а не текст?

Comment: 1. Исправил - записал в другой файл (текст)
2. Что будет, если в файл записать список, а не текст?
   -- будет текст списка